# Hibernate : Strange TypeCast Exception Thrown While retrieving records in Java from postgres database table

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

I am facing a strange type cast error ( Compile Time Error ) 
As soon as I retrieve the data from the journey table it throws following exception as it does not recognize the Object gotten from the list.

I don't know why it is complaining like this, As the object, is already of journey type and I made a list of templatized with "Journey" type, every record is supposed to be journey.

```
"INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to de.db.journeyTracker.model.journey
"
```

### Code :

```
            public static void findalljourney(Session session )
    {

        String qryAllJourney = "SELECT j.id , j.operatingday, j.linename,  j.scheduledeparture, j.scheduledeparturestopname FROM journey j";

        Query query = session.createQuery(qryAllJourney);

        List<journey> allJourney;
        allJourney = query.list();                      

        for (int i = 0; i < allJourney.size(); i++) 
        {  

            String JourneyId =   allJourney.get(i).getJourneyid().toString(); /// TypeCast Exception Occured...
        }
```

Following is the Model class for journey.

```
    public class journey 
{               
      int id ;
      String journeyid ;
      String linename ;
      Date operatingday ;
      Date realtimearrival;
      String  realtimearrivalstopname;
      String realtimearrivalstopnumber ;
      Date realtimedeparture ;
      String realtimedeparturestopname ;
      String realtimedeparturestopnumber;
      Date schedulearrival ;
      String schedulearrivalstopname ;
      String schedulearrivalstopnumber ;
      Date scheduledeparture ;
      String scheduledeparturestopname ;
      String  scheduledeparturestopnumber ;
      int arrivaldelay ;
      String direction ;
      String journeyoperator ;
      String schedulevehicletype ;
      String  vehicleid ;
      Double  distancerealtime;
      int  maximumspeedrealtime ;
      Boolean calledatallstops ;
      int departuredelay ;
      int maximumdelay; 
      int minimumdelay ;
      String phonenumber ;
      int comment_id ;
      Boolean arrivaldelayprojection ;
      Boolean  departuredelayprojection;
      Boolean maximumdelayprojection ;
      Boolean  maximumspeedrealtimedataincomplete;
      Boolean  minmaxdelaydataincomplete ;
      Boolean minimumdelayprojection ;
      Boolean realtimearrivalprojection ;
      Boolean  realtimedepartureprojection ;
       }
```

Following is hibernate config file corresponding to above journey model

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.db.journeyTracker.model.journey" table="JOURNEY">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="journeyid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="JOURNEYID" />
        </property>
        <property name="linename" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LINENAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="operatingday" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="OPERATINGDAY" />
        </property>
        <property name="realtimearrival" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="REALTIMEARRIVAL" />
        </property>
        <property name="realtimearrivalstopname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="REALTIMEARRIVALSTOPNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="realtimearrivalstopnumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="REALTIMEARRIVALSTOPNUMBER" />
        </property>
        <property name="realtimedeparture" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="REALTIMEDEPARTURE" />
        </property>
        <property name="realtimedeparturestopname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="REALTIMEDEPARTURESTOPNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="realtimedeparturestopnumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="REALTIMEDEPARTURESTOPNUMBER" />
        </property>
        <property name="schedulearrival" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="SCHEDULEARRIVAL" />
        </property>
        <property name="schedulearrivalstopname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SCHEDULEARRIVALSTOPNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="schedulearrivalstopnumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SCHEDULEARRIVALSTOPNUMBER" />
        </property>
        <property name="scheduledeparture" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="SCHEDULEDEPARTURE" />
        </property>
        <property name="scheduledeparturestopname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SCHEDULEDEPARTURESTOPNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="scheduledeparturestopnumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SCHEDULEDEPARTURESTOPNUMBER" />
        </property>
        <property name="arrivaldelay" type="int">
            <column name="ARRIVALDELAY" />
        </property>
        <property name="direction" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DIRECTION" />
        </property>
        <property name="journeyoperator" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="JOURNEYOPERATOR" />
        </property>
        <property name="schedulevehicletype" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SCHEDULEVEHICLETYPE" />
        </property>
        <property name="vehicleid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="VEHICLEID" />
        </property>
        <property name="distancerealtime" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="DISTANCEREALTIME" />
        </property>
        <property name="maximumspeedrealtime" type="int">
            <column name="MAXIMUMSPEEDREALTIME" />
        </property>
        <property name="calledatallstops" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="CALLEDATALLSTOPS" />
        </property>
        <property name="departuredelay" type="int">
            <column name="DEPARTUREDELAY" />
        </property>
        <property name="maximumdelay" type="int">
            <column name="MAXIMUMDELAY" />
        </property>
        <property name="minimumdelay" type="int">
            <column name="MINIMUMDELAY" />
        </property>
        <property name="phonenumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PHONENUMBER" />
        </property>
        <property name="comment_id" type="int">
            <column name="COMMENT_ID" />
        </property>
        <property name="arrivaldelayprojection" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="ARRIVALDELAYPROJECTION" />
        </property>
        <property name="departuredelayprojection" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="DEPARTUREDELAYPROJECTION" />
        </property>
        <property name="maximumdelayprojection" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="MAXIMUMDELAYPROJECTION" />
        </property>
        <property name="maximumspeedrealtimedataincomplete" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="MAXIMUMSPEEDREALTIMEDATAINCOMPLETE" />
          </property>
          <property name="minmaxdelaydataincomplete" type="java.lang.Boolean">
              <column name="MINMAXDELAYDATAINCOMPLETE" />
          </property>
          <property name="minimumdelayprojection" type="java.lang.Boolean">
              <column name="MINIMUMDELAYPROJECTION" />
          </property>
          <property name="realtimearrivalprojection" type="java.lang.Boolean">
              <column name="REALTIMEARRIVALPROJECTION" />
          </property>
          <property name="realtimedepartureprojection" type="java.lang.Boolean">
              <column name="REALTIMEDEPARTUREPROJECTION" />
            </property>
         </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

and following is the main hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-
configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory >
  <!-- Database connection settings -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/newTestDB</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
  <property name="connection.password">usman123</property>
  <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
  <!-- SQL dialect - generate SQL for a particular database -->
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
  <!-- Echo all executed SQL statements -->
  <property name="show_sql">false</property>
  <!-- Automatic schema creation (begin) === 
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>  
 Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <!-- Mapping resource configuration files -->
  <mapping resource="de/db/journeyTracker/model/TestTable.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="de/db/journeyTracker/model/gpspos.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="de/db/journeyTracker/model/journey.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="de/db/journeyTracker/model/trip.hbm.xml"/>


    </session-factory> </hibernate-configuration>
```

---

### Edit:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to de.db.journeyTracker.model.journey
    at de.db.journeyTracker.model.journey.findalljourney(journey.java:323)
```

I tried the following code.. AS you suggested .. But Still it is giving the exception

```
           List<Object[]> allJourney;
        allJourney = query.list();
        int Count = 0;
        for (Object[] Journey : allJourney)                 
        {                           

           String strJourneyId =  ((journey) Journey[0]).getJourneyid().toString();
           String strOperatingDay = ((journey) Journey[0]).getOperatingday().toString();
           String strLineName = ((journey) Journey[0]).getLinename();
           String strSchedualeDeparture = ((journey) Journey[0]).getScheduledeparture().toString();
           String strSchedualeDepartureStopName = ((journey) Journey[0]).getScheduledeparturestopname();


          System.out.println(strJourneyId + " " + strOperatingDay + " " + strLineName + " " + strSchedualeDeparture + " " + strSchedualeDepartureStopName);
        }
```

Comment: instead of String strJourneyId =  ((journey) Journey[0]).getJourneyid().toString(); you have write String strJourneyId =  ((Integer) Journey[0]).toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT j.id , j.operatingday, j.linename,  
       j.scheduledeparture, j.scheduledeparturestopname 
FROM journey j
```

does not select List of Journey instances. Instead it selects List of Object arrays. Elements of array match to values in select list:

```
   [0] = j.id
   [1] = j.operatingday
   ...
```

Use following instead:

```
   SELECT j FROM journey j
```

But if you want to stick with returned array, go for:

```
  List<Object[]>  allJourney = query.list(); 
  //do what ever you need to do with result:
  for (Object[] row: allJourney) {
      Integer id = (Integer) row[0];
      Date operatingday = (Date) row[1];
  }
```

Comment: No but I don't want all these column data. I mean I don't want to retrieve each record and everything. But some specific column data I want to retrieve. 
More over One more important thing.. Journey table has almost 5K records, as soon as query executed, it complains after 1 min of execution.
Like GC crashed 
OR 
Limit exceeded or ...somehow other bounnding problems ...I don't know

Comment: If you do not want to select journey records, then do not expect joyrney as result. As I said in answer, result is now Object array. IF you want to choose records based to some condition, add appropriate WHERE clause.

Comment: So, Can you not select few column data from the table in normal psql Query?

Like in above SELECT j.id,j.schedualedeparturetime,j.arrivaltime,j.operatingday

I only want to retrive the data of few columns NOT all.

Comment: Yes you can (I assume with psql you refer to HQL), and that is what you are doing, result is List of Object[], where first element (in your case) is value id, second is value of operatingday and so on. Example about how to pick values from result is added to answer.

Comment: Mikko Maunnu : Can you please look into edit..
AS now it is complaining the same...:-(

Comment: You didn't followed my suggestion at all, that's why it does not work. As said, you are not selecting instances of journey class at the moment. That's why you should not cast to journey. Just use code from the end of my answer as starting point, and maybe you will come up to something what you try to achieve. I have no idea how to make it more clear that elements in results are Object arrays, each array contains values in order defined by select list - nothing to do with class journey at this point.

Comment: Solved!! Yes you were right...I followed now completely what you said.
But One Important question!! Why we need these getters and setters then. if they cannot work in this case at all.

Comment: They do work when query is like "SELECT j FROM journey j". For such a query result is List of journey objects, then for each element in list you can call methods defined in journey class.

Comment: Thanks Mikko .. For such kind help.

Answer (score 2):

In Hibernate by using HSQL query
Try this type of query

1>String qryAllJourney = "from journey j";
this will return all journey table records without any typecasting exception.

Or - assuming that the class journey has an appropriate constructor - as an actual typesafe Java object:
String qryAllJourney = "select new journey(j.id , j.operatingday, j.linename,  j.scheduledeparture, j.scheduledeparturestopname) from journey ";

If you want more details go through this link.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: Pradeep : I don't want all records and whole data. I only want some specific data to be retrieve from Journey table ( about which I mentioned the column names ) . Later On I want the data from this table to be joined with other table.

Comment: Usman : u can select perticular columns from table as second option provided in the answer. For this all you need to do is need to provide the constructor of that class with selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a hsql query!

```
String qryAllJourney = "SELECT j.id , j.operatingday, j.linename, j.scheduledeparture, j.scheduledeparturestopname FROM journey j";
```

It should be something like this;

```
String qryAllJourney = "from Journey";
```